# Opencensus Stackdriver traces from Python app not appearing in the Trace list in GCP

Tags: python-3.x, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, opencensus

I'm comparing different tracing backend using OpenCensus.
I already have the simple OpenCensus.io python samples running fine using Zipkin and Azure Monitor.

Now I'm trying to test using GCP's Stackdriver...

I have set up the test code from Opencensus
https://opencensus.io/exporters/supported-exporters/python/stackdriver/ as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

from opencensus.common.transports.async_ import AsyncTransport
from opencensus.ext.stackdriver.trace_exporter import StackdriverExporter
from opencensus.trace.tracer import Tracer

def main():
    sde = StackdriverExporter(
        project_id=os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID"),
        transport=AsyncTransport)

    tracer = Tracer(exporter=sde)
    with tracer.span(name="doingWork") as span:
        for i in range(10):
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have set the environment variable for **GCP_PROJECT_ID** and also have my key file path for my service account JSON file set in **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**.

The service account has the ***"Cloud trace agent"*** role.

My code runs through with no errors but I can't see any info appearing in the GCP console under traces or in the monitoring dashboard.

Am I missing something?

Environment notes:
I'm testing this from my local Windows machine using Python 3.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing which is not very clear in the doc is that by default, **traces are sampled** (see source file [here](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/blob/master/opencensus/trace/samplers/__init__.py#L51)), so every call is properly logged, but only 1e-4 trace is stored. It helps to reduce costs but it is a major pain point during debug.

If you want to log all traces, you can use [AlwaysOnSampler](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/blob/master/opencensus/trace/samplers/__init__.py#L37) and pass it to the tracer :

```
import os

from opencensus.common.transports.async_ import AsyncTransport
from opencensus.ext.stackdriver.trace_exporter import StackdriverExporter
from opencensus.trace.tracer import Tracer
from opencensus.trace.samplers import AlwaysOnSampler

def main():
    sde = StackdriverExporter(
        project_id=os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID"),
        transport=AsyncTransport)

    tracer = Tracer(exporter=sde, sampler=AlwaysOnSampler())
    with tracer.span(name="doingWork") as span:
        for i in range(10):
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hope it fixes your issue !

Answer (score 1):

I was able to setup OpenCensus in GCP (in an instance on the project) by following the steps [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census#prereqs).

To set it up quickly, here are the commands I ran in a brand new Ubuntu instance

```
sudo apt-get install python3
sudo apt install python3-pip
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/master/opencensus/requirements.txt
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/master/opencensus/metrics_quickstart.py
python3 metrics_quickstart.py
```

Comment: Thanks, I can run your commands and it shows metrics in GCP (which at least shows that my service account is correct), but I still can't see traces

Comment: You could try and follow the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/python).  If that does not work, I would suggest you create a case [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/).